# Using ORDER BY takes longer to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to join two table:

```
SELECT E . * , D . * 
FROM  `basicincident` E
LEFT JOIN incident D ON E.`INC_KEY` = D.`INC_KEY` 
WHERE E.`STATE` =  "MD"
AND SUBSTRING( E.INC_DATE , -4 ) =  "2009"
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

It produces good results.

But when using `order by`, it takes longer time to produce the result.

```
SELECT  E . * , D . *
FROM  `basicincident` E 
LEFT JOIN incident D ON E.`INC_KEY` = D.`INC_KEY` 
WHERE E.`STATE` =  'MD' 
  AND SUBSTRING( E.INC_DATE , -4 ) = '2009' 
  AND E.INC_KEY >"MD0100110520090000015011111" 
ORDER BY E.INC_KEY limit 0,2
```

Comment: Is there an error? If so what is it? If it just takes longer, that's expected, MySQL has to sort the data and that takes longer.

Comment: it takes longer time to run@Blorgbeard.

Answer (score 0):

Are you use you need to have spaces around the periods?

```
SELECT E . * , D . *
```

You need to give the order, so make the SQL this way:

```
SELECT  E.*, D.* FROM `basicincident` E
    LEFT JOIN incident D ON E.`INC_KEY` = D.`INC_KEY`
    WHERE E.`STATE` = 'MD'
        AND SUBSTRING( E.INC_DATE , -4 ) = '2009'
        AND E.INC_KEY > "MD0100110520090000015011111"
    ORDER BY `E`.`INC_KEY` ASC
    LIMIT 0,2
```

Answer (score 0):

An index of E.INC_KEY and D.INC_KEY would be good for all sorts of reasons, including this.

You can try order by d.INC_KEY instead just in case something funny is going on in the optimiser.

With regards to the answer above, please disregard it!

1) You cannot ignore the ORDER BY with LIMIT.  What rows will it select if you do that?  Just whatever spews out of the query plan - most likely not what you want.  If you need an ORDER BY then you need it.  Performance concerns must not stand in the way of delivering a result that is actually correct!

2) Databases were designed to sort.  It's silly to think you can do a better job - you can't.  Use the right tool for the right job.